# What's the current state of ORMs?

Tags: performance, orm

Historically I've been completely against using ORMS for all but the most basics applications.

My reasoning has and always has been that it's a very leaky abstraction ... mostly because SQL provides a very powerful way to retreive data from a relational source which usually gets messed up by the ORM so that you lost a lot of performance to gain an appearance of not having a relational backend.

I've always thought the DATA should always be kept in the Data Base, not eat up application memory which won't scale anyway. In addition the performance hit of being to generic is harmful. For example, if I need the name and address of all the clients of my database SQL provides me with an easy way to get it, in one query. With an ORM I need to get all the clients and then each name and address, even if it's lazy loaded it's gonna take a LOT longer.

That's what I think but has any of the above changed? I'm seeing a lot of ORMS like the Entity Framework, NHibernate, etc. And they seem to have a lot of popularity lately... Are they worth it? Do they solve the problems I describe above??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read: [All Abstractions Are Failed Abstractions](https://blog.codinghorror.com/all-abstractions-are-failed-abstractions/) It should put a lot of your questions in perspective.

Performance is usually not an issue with ORM - and if you really find yourself in a situation where it is, then there usually is always the option to handcraft the SQL statements the ORM uses.

IMHO ORM give you an instant and huge development speed increase. That's why they are so popular. And using them right does not make you paint yourself in a corner. There is always the option of hand tuning the performance.

Edit:

Even though Jeff focuses on Linq to SQL all he says about abstractions and performance are equally true for NHibernate (which I know from years of real world app development). IMHO one should use by default an ORM since they are more than fast enough for the notorious 90% of situations. Reading code written for an ORM usually is more maintainable and readable especially when your code is picked up by the next developer that inherits your code. [Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/) Never forget about that guy!

In addition they give out of the box caching, lazy loading, unit of work, ... you name it. And I found that when I was not happy about the performance of the ORM *it was MY fault*. ORM do force you to adhere to good OO design practices and help you shape your Domain Model.

Comment: I've already read it but Jeff talks mostly about Linq to SQL there, and I'm interested in orms. I know the limitiations of Linq to SQL and find it a convenient tool WHEN you know how to use it and its limitations ... but ... could I say the same about ORMs?

Comment: When you say "is usually not an issue with ORM" do you mean they run fast or that you shouldn't use them if you're aiming for performance?.

Comment: IMHO they are fast enough for 90% of the tasks usually found in a RIA, Webapp or Rich Client. They usually are not the best tool for simple(!) CRUD-Apps or pure ETL scenarios.

Comment: The pragmatic answer of "raw SQL or an ORM?" is "both/and".  We use SQL where we need it (for performance, 99.999% of the time) and the ORM for the ease-of-coding otherwise.

Comment: @DarkSquid Absolutely right. Are you talking about raw sql through ORM (in other word hand crafted queries) or really raw low level sql interaction?

Answer (score 1):

On the Ruby on Rails side, ActiveRecord -- essentially an ORM -- is the basis of 95% of Rails applications (made-up statistic, but it's around there). Actually, to get to that 95% we would probably need to include other ORMs for Rails, like DataMapper.

The abstraction is leaky, and a developer can always dip down to SQL as necessary. Even when you're not using SQL directly, you have to think about number of database hits, etc. For instance, in ActiveRecord, "eager loading" is used to avoid multiple database hits, so you see stuff like this (includes the related "author" field of each Post in the initial query... it does a join under the hood, I think)

```
for post in Post.find(:all, :include => :author)
```

The point is that the abstraction leaks as do all abstractions, but that's not really the point. To decide whether to use the abstraction or not, you have to consider whether it will add to or reduce your general workload. In other words, **will you spend more time retrofitting your concepts to make the abstraction work, or is it ready to do what you need without much hacking (saving you time)?**

**I think that the abstractions that work are those that are mature:** ActiveRecord has been around the block a ton (as has Hibernate), so it provides an **abstract** way to patch most of the leaks you would normally be worried about, without explicitly rolling your own lower-level solution (i.e., without writing SQL).

Beyond the learning curve, I think that ORMs are an amazing time-saver for most of your database access, and that most apps actually do make quite "normal" use of the DB. While it may not be your case whatsoever, eschewing an ORM for direct DB access is often a case of early, and unnecessary, optimization.

**Edit:** I hadn't seen this, but the Jeff quote is

> Does this abstraction make our code at
>   least a little easier to write? To
>   understand? To troubleshoot? Are we
>   better off with this abstraction than
>   we were without it?

saying essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the more modern ORM's are really powerful tools that solve a lot of real world problems. The good ORM's don't try to hide the relational model from you, but actually leverage it to make OO programming more powerful. They really aren't abstractions in the sense that they let you ignore the "lowlevel" details of relational algebra, instead they are toolkits that let you build abstractions on the relational model and make it easier to bring in data into the imperative model, track the changes and push them back to the database. The SQL language really doesn't provide any good way to factor out common predicates into composable, reusable components to achieve businesstule level abstractions.

Sure there is a performance hit, but it's mostly a constant factor thing as you can make the ORM issue what ever SQL you would issue yourself. Like for your name and address example, in SQLAlchemy you'd just do

```
for name, address in session.query(Client.name, Client.address):
    # process data
```

and you're done. But where the ORM helps you is when you have reusable relations and predicates. For instance, say you have defined a way to join to a client's favorited items, and a predicate to see if it is on sale. Then you can get the list of clients that have some of their favorite items on sale while also fetching the assigned salesperson with the following query:

```
potential_sales = (session.query(Client).join(Client.favorite_items)
                  .filter(Item.is_on_sale)
                  .options(eagerload(Client.assigned_salesperson)))
```

Atleast for me, the intent of the query is a lot faster to write, clearer and easier to understand when written like this, instead of a dozen lines of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

As to any abstraction, you'll have to pay either in form of performance, or leaking. I agree with you in being against ORM's, since SQL is a clean and elegant language. I've sort of written my own little frameworks which do this things for me, but hey, then I sat there with my own ORM (but with a little more control over it than for example Hibernate). The people behind Hibernate states that it is fast. It should be able to do about 95% of the boring work against your database (simple queries, updates etc..) but gives you freedom to do the last 5% yourself if you want (you could always write your own mappings in special cases).

I think most of the popularity stems from that many programmers are lazy and want established frameworks to do the dirty boring persistence job for them (I can understand that), but the price of an abstraction will always be there. I would consider my options thoroughly before choosing to use an ORM in a serious project.